# bind keyboard enter to button click windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Can someone redirect me or show me one example about how do I bind my button click of xaml to enter key on keyboard in windows phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly with binding. You'll have to interrogate the specified key in code and then trigger the same action that you fire on button click.

XAML:

```
<TextBox KeyUp="CheckForEnterPressed" />
```

CS:

```
    private void CheckForEnterPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // Do something appropriate here
        }
    }
```

If you don't want to have this code in the page you could encapsulate it into a control.

Comment: thanks that worked..actually i figured it out, immediately after i asked it